# Sum and Averages of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, sum, average

I am working on an array problem for my college course and I'm trying to find the sum and the average of an array.  Here's the code I have so far.

```
public class Module55
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {

   //declare the array to have 10 items for 10 weeks
   //also declare sum as an int and average as a double to accommodate for decimal points

      int[] weeks = new int[10];
      int sum = 0;
      double average = 0;

   //declare the array values

      weeks[0]= 2;
      weeks[1]= 4;
      weeks[2]= 8;
      weeks[3]= 10;
      weeks[4]= 14;
      weeks[5]= 16;
      weeks[6]= 20;
      weeks[7]= 22;
      weeks[8]= 24;
      weeks[9]= 26;

   // determine sum of the array values

     for (int index = 0; index < weeks.length; index++) weeks[index] = index;
        sum = sum + weeks[index];
        System.out.println("The total miles ran in 10 weeks is " + sum);

   // determine the average of the array values

     if (weeks.length != 0)
        average = sum / weeks.length;
     else
        average = 0;

     System.out.println("The average of the miles ran in 10 weeks is " + average);
     }
}
```

I know that the average works but I'm stuck on the sum. The problem I'm having is I cant seem to initialize the values in the array so that I can provide a sum for them.  What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you want to remove the loop statement `weeks[index] = index;`? It simply doesn't make sense. Furthermore the next line `sum = sum + weeks[index];` seems to be the loop statement.

Comment: Your for-loop only has one statement in it: `weeks[index] = index;`

Comment: Just updated my answer, which also solves your precision problem, you can check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in your code;

#### A) For-loop assignment

You don't need to make the first assignment, just adding sum to the week[index] is ok;

```
    for (int index = 0; index < weeks.length; index++)
        sum = sum + weeks[index];
```

#### B) Calculating the average

Sum is defined as an `int` which is a primitive integer, because of that, the division of an integer to an integer, the output is an integer which is not precise. Output of the division (45/10) is casted to integer, then assigned to double which is rounded off to 4, then casted to double again, and '4.0' became the result.

To avoid this unprecise result, cast sum to the double as below;

```
average = (double)sum / weeks.length;
```

The corrected version of your code is as below;

## Demo

```
public class Module55 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // declare the array to have 10 items for 10 weeks
        // also declare sum as an int and average as a double to accommodate for
        // decimal points

        int[] weeks = new int[10];
        int sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        // declare the array values

        weeks[0] = 2;
        weeks[1] = 4;
        weeks[2] = 8;
        weeks[3] = 10;
        weeks[4] = 14;
        weeks[5] = 16;
        weeks[6] = 20;
        weeks[7] = 22;
        weeks[8] = 24;
        weeks[9] = 26;

        // determine sum of the array values
        for (int index = 0; index < weeks.length; index++)
            sum = sum + weeks[index];

        System.out.println("The total miles ran in 10 weeks is " + sum);

        // determine the average of the array values
        if (weeks.length != 0)
            average = (double)sum / weeks.length;
        else
            average = 0;

        System.out.println("The average of the miles ran in 10 weeks is " + average);
    }
}
```

## Output

```
The total miles ran in 10 weeks is 146
The average of the miles ran in 10 weeks is 14.6
```

#### And a note for scope

And one last note about the **scope**, check out this code;

```
 for (int index = 0; index < weeks.length; index++)
    weeks[index] = index;
    sum = sum + weeks[index];
    System.out.println("The total miles ran in 10 weeks is " + sum);
```

In the `for-loop`, because that no brackets are used, only the first statement under the `for-loop` will be considered in the `scope` of the loop by the compiler. That's why, for the next line, the compiler is giving error about the index because index is defined inside the `scope` of the `for-loop`.

Comment: There's still the problem that `weeks[index] = index;` is overwriting all the values assigned earlier.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the broken down explanation of what I was not getting!

Comment: I'm glad, and by the way, I've also added a note to my answer just to point out that why compiler warning about the index. Compiler warn about that because it is not considered inside of the for-loop by the compiler.

Comment: Cool I really appreciate that! Thank you again for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

you need to use brackets in your for loop. currently your code is evaluating like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < weeks.length; index++) 
{
    weeks[index] = index;
}
sum = sum + weeks[index];
System.out.println("The total miles ran in 10 weeks is " + sum);
```

you want your code to evaluate like this

```
for (int index = 0; index < weeks.length; index++) 
{
    weeks[index] = index; //logical issue, what does this line achieve?
    sum = sum + weeks[index];
}
System.out.println("The total miles ran in 10 weeks is " + sum);
```

This will at least solve your procedural problems but you will still need to take a look at your logic. Try using breakpoints to debug your code.

Comment: Do you really think that the statements `weeks[index] = index` and `System.out.println(...)` belong into the loop? The first one overwrites all values set before. I think, he has to simply remove that one.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I agree. I edited my answer to note that it will solve procedural issues, but logic issues like the one you raised are another problem

Comment: Thanks. Syntax is really tough when you're new to Java.  I appreciate the help @NoamHacker

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to achieve this in Java 8 is to use the built in mechanisms for gathering statistics:

```
int[] weeks = {3, 4, 6, 9, 10};
IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.of(weeks).summaryStatistics();
System.out.println("sum = " + stats.getSum() + "; average = " + stats.getAverage());
```

Comment: no need to write getsum or get average i got that automatically in output

Comment: using summaryStatistics() is enough.

Comment: Yes `IntSummaryStatistics` has a sensible `toString` - but the question asked for sum and average so I was showing how to extract those.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0;i < weeks.length) {
    sum += weeks[i];
}

System.out.println("Sum is:" + sum);
```

Comment: He asked to find average not sum need to  change last line to sum/weeks.length.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you simply don't need the line weeks[index] = index;.
And for average you have to cast the sum to double if you want to get the average in double as you have declared the sum as int.

```
public class Module55
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {

   //declare the array to have 10 items for 10 weeks
   //also declare sum as an int and average as a double to accommodate for decimal points

      int[] weeks = {2,4,8,10,14,16,20,22,24,26};
      int sum = 0;
      double average = 0;

   // determine sum of the array values

     for (int index = 0; index < weeks.length; index++) 
         //weeks[index] = index;
         sum = sum + weeks[index];
         System.out.println("The total miles ran in 10 weeks is " + sum);

   // determine the average of the array values

     if (weeks.length != 0)
        average = (double)sum / weeks.length;
     else
        average = 0;

     System.out.println("The average of the miles ran in 10 weeks is " + average);
     }
}
```

The total miles ran in 10 weeks is 146

The average of the miles ran in 10 weeks is 14.6

Answer (score 1):

Summing an array of numbers and dividing by n to get the average like this will not get the correct value - you should not compute the average using integer division. 
Also, this approach might work for the example shown, but not in general. For example, try using this code to find the average of these two value: (INT_MAX-6) and (INT_MAX-2).

Answer (score 1):

you can find this handy with lambdas.The code looks something like this.

```
int weeks[] = {1,2,3,4};
List<Integer> asd = IntStream.of(weeks).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
//asd.forEach(System.out::println);
//this outputs average
System.out.println(asd.stream().mapToDouble(val -> val).sum()/asd.size());
//this outputs sum
System.out.println(asd.stream().mapToInt(val -> val).sum());
//another way to achieve this thanks to commenter
System.out.println(IntStream.of(asd).summaryStatistics());
```

Comment: dont forget to  import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;import java.util.List;

Comment: Actually it's even simpler than that in Java 8: `IntStream.of(weeks).summaryStatistics()`. Then use `getAverage`, `getSum` etc on the result.

Comment: can you post example link i got some errors while i am trying.

Comment: I'll post an answer for you to look at

Answer (score 1):

The corrected code.  While calculating average you have cast on of the varibale to double else you will get the average as integer

```
public class Mod55 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //declare the array to have 10 items for 10 weeks
        //also declare sum as an int and average as a double to accommodate for decimal points
        int[] weeks = new int[]{2, 4, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20, 22, 24, 26};
        int sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        // determine sum of the array values
        for (int index = 0; index < weeks.length; index++) {
            sum += weeks[index];
        }
        System.out.println("The total miles ran in 10 weeks is " + sum);

        // determine the average of the array values
        if (weeks.length != 0) {
            average = (double)sum / weeks.length;
        } else {
            average = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("The average of the miles ran in 10 weeks is " + average);
    }
}
```

Java8 You could achieve the same thing like this.

```
        int[] weeks = new int[]{2, 4, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20, 22, 24, 26};
        int sum = Arrays.stream(weeks)
                 .sum();
        double average = Arrays.stream(weeks).average().orElse(0);
```